# sorting Custom date class in Java

Tags: java

I have created my own date class java and used toString method to output my own date format.

Here is Date class

```
public class Date {
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;


    public Date() {
    this.day = 0;
    this.month = 0;
    this.year = 0;
    }

    public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Date(Date d) {
        this.day = d.day;
        this.month = d.month;
        this.year = d.year;
    }

        @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" +this.day+"."+this.month+"."+this.year;
    }

}
```

now I have to use this class in Main class and sort the date in ascending order. Everything seems fine but the netbeans gives error says "parse cannot be applied to Date" but I have used toString method in my Date class already.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Date> date = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Date date1 = new Date(28,7,2017);
    Date date2 = new Date(1,10,2017);
    Date date3 = new Date(15,9,2018);
    Date date4 = new Date(25,11,2018);
    Date date5 = new Date(5,6,2014);

    date.add(date1);
    date.add(date2);
    date.add(date3);
    date.add(date4);
    date.add(date5);
        sortDates(date);

        for (Date SortedDate : date) {
            System.out.println(SortedDate);
        }

    }

    private static void sortDates(ArrayList<Date> date) {
        Collections.sort(date, new Comparator<Date>() {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            @Override
            public int compare(Date o1, Date o2) {
                try {
                    return f.parse(o1).compareTo(f.parse(o2));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `return f.parse(o1.toString()).compareTo(f.parse(o2.toString()));`

Comment: I tried but it debug throws error `exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1.10.2017"`

Comment: Fixed.. I had bug on DateFormat (dd.MM.yyyy);

Comment: What is causing you to write a custom date class? Java’s Date class has built in methods for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly call toString on o1 and o2 and change the toString method to generate the same format as provided to SimpleDateFormat